# Selenium Python script works only command line php, but not in browsers

Tags: python, php, nginx, selenium-webdriver

I have nginx, php server, and python selenium installed, my python selenium script works perfectly in command line php, but not via nginx server browser. Tried some python codes, all work  in  browsers except selenium code.
No error in browsers, curl.

exec.php

```php
$selenium = ('python3 /var/www/html/selenium/test.py');
echo shell_exec($selenium);
```

test.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('http://localhost/info.php')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Tried in nginx  root directory, with php  unix and tcp socket

Comment: what is error displayed?

Comment: What error do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded from selenium 4 to selenium 3 and chrome, chromderiver 74. now it works in browser too.